# Check if \n is there, if not Insert \n at a particular position in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list into which need to insert specific character `\n`.

However, at the same time this is gonna be inside two for loops. In that case, wee need to check if `\n` is already present at the location or not.

If present don't insert otherwise insert `\n` at that position.

```
# position of '\n' from previous list
# '\n' needs to be exactly at the same position as in the previous lsit

indexes = [i for i, val in enumerate(input_list) if val == '\n']

ncol = some value

nrows = some value

for column in range(1, ncol):

    for row in range(1, nrows):
        abc.append(ws2.cell(row = row, column=column).value)
        if ind in indexes:
            abc.insert(ind, '\n')
        #print('abc: ', abc)
        concatABC = '\n'.join(abc)
        #print('Concate: ', concatABC)
        ws.cell(row=(nrows), column=(column)).value = concatABC
    del abc[:]
```

At the `if` loop, I have to check for `\n` as already there or not. This doesn't make sense to insert it each time as it is needed only once.

I am generating excel file with the specific data structure given in input_list which was generated using input TXT file.

Sorry for the confusion,

the value of ind is from list indexes, where I am getting the position of '\n' from original input list. In between in my code, I am extracting data from xml file and putting it to Excel. Now, while concatenating this data in last Excel row/cell, I need to keep the format as given in the TXT file.

My problem is only the input list is stable all other things are either coming from XML or updating while iteration in loop.

@wim: Input would be..
input_list = ['abc', '\n', 'def', 'ghi', '\n', 'jkl', 'mno']

we get the index of \n from this inputlist then in my excel, I concatenate all the top rows and put \n exactly where it is in the input list. that's whole story.

Output in Excel:

row 1: abc

row 2: def

row 3: ghi

row 4: jkl

row 5: mno

row 6: abc
           Empty line (\n)
           def
           ghi
           Empty line (\n)
           jkl
           mno

Comment: an example input and output would really help here

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function like this:

```
lis=[1,2,3,4,5,'\n','abc','a']

def ins(pos):

    if lis[pos]=='\n':
        print ('found')
    else:
        lis.insert(pos,'\n')
```

**output:**

```
>>> ins(3)
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, '\n', 4, 5, '\n', 'abc', 'a']
>>> ins(5)
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, '\n', 4, '\n', 5, '\n', 'abc', 'a']
>>> ins(7)
found
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, '\n', 4, '\n', 5, '\n', 'abc', 'a']
>>> ins(len(lis)-1)
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3, '\n', 4, '\n', 5, '\n', 'abc', '\n', 'a']
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it works with the already established list.

In my case, the list is iterating inside the loop and adding new element each time...so I can't use this function, the result I get is list out of bounds....But I think, I have solved the problem, once it is finished will post below as answer.